# Is there a way to kill a PHP program while it's working?

Tags: php, process, kill

Is there a way to kill a PHP program while it's working?  I know in Linux/Unix I can do

```
ps -u [username]
```

And it will tell me what processes are running.  To stop a process I just enter

```
kill [process #]
```

With PHP is there any way to see what processes are currently running on the remote server and kill an individual program from completion?  Ideally using exec()?

The reason that I ask is that I am on a shared hosting environment and I work on & test my programs directly on the server...  Every now and then I'll do something silly like enter a ridiculous  number of loops, accidentally, where it can take several minutes to an hour to actually complete.

Seeing that there is virtually no information on the subject, I thought it would be an interesting question to throw out there.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not kill the process in question from the *nix shell?  Are you trying to have a php program which does so automatically based on identifying them with some criteria?  Essentially, if they are owned by your userid you should be able to kill them; if a scripting language is decent it should allow you to execute arbitrary shell commands - so not clear where the problem is?

Comment: Why don't you just do `kill` with `exec()` (or SSH in and do the same). You can also limit the time a PHP program can run using `set_time_limit()`.

Comment: Well, I tried `echo exec("ps")` on a new page and it returned one process ID#.  I tried killing it, but I'm pretty sure it's just listing the ID to the new page that's calling `exec()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask your hosting provider for SSH access and do that in Unix way. Still you can emulate shell access with a `system` function and friends:

```
exec("ps --no-header -eo pid,user,comm", $output);
foreach ($output as $line) {
    $line = preg_split('#\s+#', trim($line));
    echo "PID: $line[0] USER: $line[1] PRG: $line[2]\n";
}
```

Disclaimer: you probably won't be able to kill Apache processes even if you will have shell access.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is really good.  The one thing that confused me is why `echo exec("ps")` didn't output an array... I'm assuming it has something to do with `$output`?

Answer (score 1):

if u have some infinite loop or something, put this

```
    while(1){

    if(!file_exists("continue.txt")){
    die("Stop");
    }

//Your Code here.

    }
```

so when u delete that file "continue.txt", your script dies.

Answer (score -1):

You can change set_time_limt settings before the risk of a loop, making the script stop after 10 seconds if you wish.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: The user was asking how to stop a running process, not how to prevent one from running too long